# Visual Studio 2010 Unit Test not showing in Dropdown menu

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, nunit

I installed NUnit to show up in the Test Framework dropdown menu in Visual Studio 2010. The setup went good and NUnit now shows up in the Test Framework dropdown menu for my **ASP.NET MVC2** projects. My problem is the Visual Studio Test has disappeared from the Test Framework dropdown menu. I ran a repair on Visual Studio but that did not resolve my problem.

Does anyone know how to get the Visual Studio Test option back in the Test Framework dropdown menu?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened. My solution was uninstall VS 2010. Reinstall VS 2010, redo the NUnit install. Now both NUnit and Visual Studio Test are displayed in the Test Framwork dropdown menu.